# Difference between For and Map in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, loops, dictionary

Please let me know what the difference is between these operations. The first code works ok:

```
1) for elem in(mr)
     elem.shedule = Date.new(date.year, date.month, date.day)  
   end
```

but I would like to use `map`:

```
2) mr.map!{ |elem| elem.shedule = Date.new(date.year, date.month, date.day) }
```

and the second code returns an error:

```
 NoMethodError in Events#index

Showing C:/Sites/calend/app/views/events/_calendar.html.erb where line #9 raised:

undefined method `shedule' for Thu, 04 Apr 2013:Date

Extracted source (around line #9):

6:   </h2>
7:   <%= calendar_for(@repeats, :year => @date.year, :month => @date.month) do |calendar| %>
8:     <%= calendar.head('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday') %>
9:     <%= calendar.day(:day_method => :shedule) do |date, events| %>
10:       <%= date.day %> <%= link_to '+', new_event_path(date: date) %>
11:       <ul>
12:         <% for event in events %>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using `map` in the wrong way, you should use `each` instead.
Your code should be:

```
mr.each do |elem| 
  elem.shedule = Date.new(date.year, date.month, date.day)
end
```

`map` replaces each element in the Array with the value returned by the block (see Linuxios comment below), in you example the block returns a Date object. `map!` performs the same operation in place without creating a new Array, thus in you example `mr` is an Array of Date objects and not of Events.

Moreover the use of `for` is quite uncommon in Ruby code, it is usually replaced with `each` since:

```
[1, 2, 3].each do |x|
  puts x
end
```

is almost equivalent to (see Mladen Jablanović comment to this answer for the differences) :

```
for x in [1, 2, 3]
  puts x
end
```

and the former is considered more "Rubyish".

Comment: `for` and `each` differ in that, that `each` receives a block (therefore a new scope), while `for` retains in the surrounding one. This means that, if you introduce a new local variable in the block, it will not be visible after `end`. With `for`, this is not the case.

Comment: Just a small note: `map` doesn't replace the elements, rather, it creates a new array. `map!` replaces the elements.